# HAML & RoR: Auto-convert apostrophes, etc., to ASCII HTML entities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ascii, haml

Is there anyway to have HAML automatically convert all my apostrophe's `'` to the HTML character entity equivalents `’` (`&rsquo;`)?

Ditto with all the other characters that one would want to convert (dashes, double-quotes, etc.) for better online readability.

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wouldn't be something HAML would do. If you want it done, write a helper and use gsub to substitute the characters you want.

Comment: Perhaps it is something that HAML "doesn't" do, but that doesn't mean that it isn't something that it "wouldn't" do. HAML already parses what's in `.haml` files and rewrites it for semantically correct HTML, so it stands to reason that it "could" do this replacement. It would be so nice to just type `it's possible` rather than `it&rsquo;s possible`, you know?